# Create a function with get_template_part inside

Tags: php, wordpress, function

Is it possible to create a function shortcode in wordpress with get_template_part() in functions.php ?

Something like this

```
function custom_code( $atts ){
        echo get_template_part( 'page', 'example' );
    }
 add_shortcode( 'custom', 'custom_code' );
```

thanks

Comment: there is a site for WordPress developement questions : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, with a small function, that render the template and get back the code.

```
add_shortcode( 'my_shortcode', 'fb_get_template' );
function fb_get_template() {
    
    ob_start();
    get_template_part( 'my_template' );
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    
    return $content;
}
```